# No time zone options in install wizard

Tags: installation, ce-1.8.0.0, timezone

The timezone dropdown is empty and I cannot get pass locale selection in magento 1.8 install wizard.

I copied all the files to hosting ... so whats the idea?

btw ... this solution http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/288663/ does not work.

Answer (score 3):

The timezone select is rendered by the method `Mage_Install_Block_Locale::getTimezoneSelect()` that looks like this:

```
public function getTimezoneSelect()
{
    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
        ->setName('config[timezone]')
        ->setId('timezone')
        ->setTitle(Mage::helper('install')->__('Time Zone'))
        ->setClass('required-entry')
        ->setValue($this->getTimezone())
        ->setOptions(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getOptionTimezones())
        ->getHtml();
    return $html;
}
```

So most probably `Mage::app()->getLocale()->getOptionTimezones()` returns null or an empty array.
You can start debugging there.
The values come from the file `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/supplementalData.xml` path `timezoneData->mapTimezones->mapZone`.
Make sure this file is correct and has values for these tags.
Also make sure that you php version parses xml files correctly.